# IIS rewrite rule - invalid rule

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I'm trying to convert some mod_rewrite rules to IIS 7.5 rules in my web.config

I'm having a problem with the following as IIS gives the error of -

"The expression "^(?!/(___generated|images)/.*$)" contains an escape sequence that is not valid."

The rule is:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*[A-Z].*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(?!/(\_\_\_generated|images)/.*$)" ignoreCase="false" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http\://{C:1}{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Any help would be appreciated and yes I need to brush up on my regex!

Thanks

Comment: Try to replace `\_\_\_` with underscores only. Underscore is not a special character and does not need to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: @Lost_Cause you should pop that in an answer because it's correct.

Comment: @kev yeah I will have to check when it's appropriate to use comments and when to put in the whole answer. Seems weird to use answer for one sentence though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `_\_\_`with underscores only. Underscore is not a special character and does not need to be escaped with a backslash.